# Parallel jQuery effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, queue, effects

I want to execute two effects in parallel. A jQuery UI "transfer" animation and a "fadeIn" on another element. They should begin and end at the same time.

My code so far:

```
    $('#foo').hover(function() {
        $(this).effect("transfer", {
            to: "#transition-target",
            className: "ui-effects-transfer"
        }, 300, function() {
            $('#bar').fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
```

I understand that both effects are executed one after another. Is it possible to achieve parallel effect execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the fadeIn function in the "callback" of the effect. The callback is triggered/run only after the animation has finished. This should help you out..

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {

    $(this).effect("transfer", {
        to: "#transition-target",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"
    }, 300);

    $('#bar').fadeIn(300);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#foo').hover(function() {
$('#bar').fadeIn(300);
        $(this).effect("transfer", {
            to: "#transition-target",
            className: "ui-effects-transfer"
        }, 300  );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 or more parallel fx using [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

Two run the two animations in parallel i.e. simultaneously use `queue : false` and don't put the second animation in the callback function of the first one like this:

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
    $(this).effect("transfer", {
        to: "#transition-target",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"
    }, { duration:300, queue: false});
    $('#bar').fadeIn({ duration: 300, queue: false});
});
```